# How to execute Get-CrmConnection inside scheduled task

Tags: powershell, dynamics-crm, xrm

I have same issue while connecting to on premise instance with followings commands :

```
[System.Net.ServicePointManager]::SecurityProtocol = [System.Net.SecurityProtocolType]::Tls12
$conn = Get-CrmConnection -Credential $Credential -OrganizationName "$crmOrganization" -ServerUrl $ServerUrl -ErrorAction Stop -Verbose
```

Inside log, we can see following error :

> Microsoft.Xrm.Tooling.CrmConnectControl Error   2   16.02.2021
> 19:38:36  Error Message: Can't connect to Microsoft Common Data
> Service - XXXX-TEST.
>
> Source : mscorlib Method : HandleReturnMessage Date : 16.02.2021 Time
> : 19:38:36 Error : System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not
> set to an instance of an object. at
> Microsoft.Xrm.Sdk.Utility.ConfigurationProvider.RetrieveOrganizationVersion(Guid
> organizationId, LocatorServiceContext locatorServiceContext) at
> Microsoft.Xrm.Sdk.Utility.ConfigurationProvider.CheckOrganizationStateAndVersion(Guid
> organizationId, EndpointVersion version, LocatorServiceContext
> locatorServiceContext) at
> Microsoft.Xrm.Sdk.Utility.ConfigurationProvider.RetrieveOrganizationIds(ClaimsPrincipal
> claimsPrincipal, EndpointVersion version) at
> Microsoft.Xrm.Sdk.Discovery.DiscoveryServiceProviderBase.RetrieveOrganizations(ClaimsPrincipal
> claimsPrincipal, OrganizationRelease release, EndpointAccessType
> endpointAccessType) at
> Microsoft.Xrm.Sdk.Discovery.RetrieveOrganizationsRequestProcessor.Process(IDiscoveryServiceProvider
> serviceProvider) at
> Microsoft.Crm.Sdk.V5.DiscoveryService.Execute(DiscoveryRequest
> request): Microsoft Dynamics CRM has experienced an error. Reference
> number for administrators or support: #ACA97262 Stack Trace : Server
> stack trace: at
> System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannel.HandleReply(ProxyOperationRuntime
> operation, ProxyRpc& rpc) at
> System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannel.Call(String action,
> Boolean oneway, ProxyOperationRuntime operation, Object[] ins,
> Object[] outs, TimeSpan timeout) at
> System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannelProxy.InvokeService(IMethodCallMessage
> methodCall, ProxyOperationRuntime operation) at
> System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannelProxy.Invoke(IMessage
> message)
>
> Exception rethrown at [0]: at
> System.Runtime.Remoting.Proxies.RealProxy.HandleReturnMessage(IMessage
> reqMsg, IMessage retMsg) at
> System.Runtime.Remoting.Proxies.RealProxy.PrivateInvoke(MessageData&
> msgData, Int32 type) at
> Microsoft.Xrm.Sdk.Discovery.IDiscoveryService.Execute(DiscoveryRequest
> request) at
> Microsoft.Xrm.Sdk.Client.DiscoveryServiceProxy.Execute(DiscoveryRequest
> request) at
> Microsoft.Xrm.Tooling.Connector.CrmWebSvc.DiscoverOrganizations(Uri
> discoveryServiceUri, Uri homeRealmUri, ClientCredentials
> clientCredentials, ClientCredentials deviceCredentials, CrmLogEntry
> logSink) at
> Microsoft.Xrm.Tooling.Connector.CrmWebSvc.DiscoverOrganizations(Uri
> discoveryServiceUri, Uri homeRealmUri, NetworkCredential
> networkCredential, CrmLogEntry logSink) at
> Microsoft.Xrm.Tooling.CrmConnectControl.CrmConnectionManager.ValidateServerConnection(CrmOrgByServer
> selectedOrg)

Anybody who can help me ?

thanks.

Comment: Try adding the domain to your credential like this : DOMAIN\user.name, this may solve your problem. What I can see is that you have "object reference not set to an instance of an object". My guess is that the script is crashing somewhere and can't proceed because variable can't be filled. Are you running this script with the highest priviledge ? Can you add an execution policy bypass in the schedule task and see if it helps ?

Comment: Hello, I used followed login as username@domain, I already user the highest privileges and trying with -Unrestricted.